# Url syntax with List property on complex type

Tags: asp.net-web-api

**Model:**

```
[DataContract]
public class Employee
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [DataMember(Name ="id")]
    public int Id{ get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "fullName")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Department
{
    public Department()
    {
        this.Employees = new List<Employee>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "employees")]
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri]Department model)
{
   if (ModelState.IsValid)
   {

   }
   return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);

}
```

**Url :**  "http://localhost:2070/home/get/?id=1&name=IT&Employees=1,John"

I am trying to invoke above URL and the Model does not read the Employees. Other property like int,double,string,decimal are read by the Model.
Can anyone help me on what is the correct format in passing List thru Url.

Also, I dont want to decorate each of my class with modelbinders nor the parameter in my controller.

Tech : WebApi, .Net3.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the index of the list and property to bind with when using FromUri and list/array

Try it this way

```
http://localhost:2070/home/get/?id=1&name=IT&Employees[0].Id=1&Employees[0].Name=John
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You save my day. Can you give me a hint on how to make from `Employees[0].Id=1&Employees[0].Name=John` to `Employees[0]=1,John`

Comment: Np:-) with FromUri attribute, the ”1,John” cant be done. If the object is to complex I would use http POST and read the object from the body with FromBody attribute instead.